Nginx Dynamic client_max_body_size (to mitigate PHP HashDOS issue)
As much as i can see the client_max_body_size is not so dynamic as I thought. I need it though to reduce the size that can be sent as JSON in a body to mitigate the HashDOS issue (https://github.com/bk2204/php-hash-dos). My initial thought was to do something along the lines of
map "$content_type" $client_max_body_size {
    "multipart/form-data" 500M; # or variable ${MULTIPART_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
    "application/json"    10M;  # or variable ${JSON_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
    default               1M;   # or variable ${DEFAULT_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
}
client_max_body_size $client_max_body_size;

but i can only place map in the http block and client_max_body_size in http, server, location, so placing anything in an if block doesn't work. Also it doesn't take any variables, according to the comment here.
So does anyone have other ideas, or has already solved this with nginx?
